# Unable to use prevent default option on button click using Vue.js

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

Here what I am trying is I have dynamic data and displaying it in section and section is clickable and under that, I have 2 buttons called edit, del after clicking those buttons also it should trigger some action.

The problem I am facing is even though I am clicking edit action but the section button click also getting triggered and I tried putting @click.prevent still facing the issue.

what I need is whenever I click on edit or del the section action should not trigger below is my code sandbox URL

https://codesandbox.io/s/vuejs-with-import-json-example-forked-tjn45?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark

code

```
<template>
  <div>
    <section
      style="border-style: dotted"
      v-for="(name, index) in names"
      :key="index"
      @click.prevent="methodOne"
    >
      <div>
        <button @click.prevent="edit">Edit</button>
        <button @click="del">Del</button>
      </div>
      <div>
        {{ name }}
      </div>
    </section>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import states from "../assets/data.json";
export default {
  name: "HelloWorld",
  computed: {
    names() {
      return states.accounts.map((item) => {
        return item.name;
      });
    },
  },
  methods: {
    methodOne() {
      alert("Method One");
    },
    edit() {
      alert("Edit");
    },
    del() {
      alert("DELETE");
    },
  },
};
</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is event propagation issue, `.prevent` don't stop the propagation, Use [`.stop`](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/events.html#Event-Modifiers) instead of `.prevent`. Update [example here](https://codesandbox.io/s/vuejs-with-import-json-example-forked-tjn45?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark&file=/src/components/HelloWorld.vue:197-201)

```
<div>
  <button @click.stop="edit">Edit</button>
  <button @click.stop="del">Del</button>
</div>
```